# How to add auto-fill otp and resend otp feature in flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to add a resend otp button in my flutter app but I am not able to understand what I should do here.

Also, I am trying to auto-fill the received otp in the app. I know I have to use the `sms_autofill:` package, but I am not sure if it will work on my single textfield.

Please let me know if there's a better solution to it. Thank you!

Comment: you can also use https://pub.dev/packages/otp_autofill this package which works for me.